# EBS integration kit not working with Zencart

Tags: php, shopping-cart, zen-cart

I am using ebs integration kit downloaded from [here](https://support.ebs.in/app/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/181/7/zencart-integration-kit-ver-25), but after payment it is giving me this error.  I am using zencart v1.3.9h
[image]

I think it is not sending data via POST.  How can i tell where the problem is?
Can i convert it into GET?

Comment: Have you tried reaching the page by putting the url into the browser?  Thats the first thing I'd try

Comment: Yes... Its just show same page.Thats why i think that ebs is not getting params when i am doing checkout.And is there anything like , i cant get expected result on my localhost?

Comment: I have got this.EBS use your domain name to validate.So if you are using test domain then need to enter there test domain details.Please use ccavenue , ebs customer care is very slow..